# Send Facebook chat messages via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, dom

I am writing a Firefox addon, which should be able to send/intercept Facebook chat messages, while chatting in the browser.

I am able to intercept messages, but I don't know, how to trigger the message sending event autonomously.

As I could not find out how to make the ajax request for sending a message myself, my approach was to fill the chat box `textarea` and then trigger the `keydown`-Event for `ENTER` to create and submit a message.

I guess there is a more appropriate and clean way to accomplish this?
How can I trigger the AJAX event for sending a message in an open chatbox via JavaScript?

Comment: Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/ or http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Answer (score 0):

To fire an AJAX request from a text box input would be to check the character code that you input, which for enter would be

```
if(characterCode == 13)
```

Which could then be used to fire the request; a full example would be

```
$("textarea").live("keydown",function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        $.ajax({
             //you know the rest
        });
    }
});
```