# Javascript Submit Facebook Chat

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am developing a browser plugin where I need to send Facebook chat message using JavaScript(the Plugin will deliver the javascript to Facebook page). But unfortunately i could not find any submit button(because Enter key is basically used to send chat messages) or equivalent event for sending chat messages using Plugin Injected javascript even after reviewing good amount of client side source code of facebook.

So kindly help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submit buttons, most chat interfaces send whenever the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. Check this question out, 
[Send Facebook chat messages via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902973/send-facebook-chat-messages-via-javascript) , and let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. I have already seen that question, but the thing is Facebook POST many others token with chat messages.I could not figure out those parameters from FB source code.Its still not clear how can i trigger the "message sending event autonomously".